# Use Template Strings with webpack [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm fairly new to webpack, and when compiling my code I came across this error.

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/html-loader/index.js):
Error: Line 539: Unexpected identifier
```

And this is the line that its referring too.

```
return `background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, ${this.gradientStart}, ${this.gradientEnd});`
```

Is it possible to allow Template Strings in Webpack?
This is the inside of my webpack config

```
const html = {
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  // exclude: /\.html$/,
  use: [
  {
  loader: 'html-loader',
  options: {
    interpolate: true,
   },
  },
 ],
};
```

Comment: does this have the same problem?: `"background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, " + this.gradientStart + ", " + this.gradientEnd + ");";`  ie: are you sure template strings are the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template strings are a feature of es2015. Webpack does not understand es2015 by default to ensure compatibility with as many legacy devices as possible. You need to use a loader that will transpile es2015 into an older version of javascript. You can use "babel-loader" with the preset webpack environment that has support for many features of modern javascript.

You need to download @babel/core & @babel/preset-env for webpack by running the following command:

```
    npm install --save-dev -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

You need to add the following to your webpack.config.js

```
    module: {
       rules: [
         { 
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           use: {
               loader: 'babel-loader',
               options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
               }
           }
         }
       ]
     },
```